# Unmanaged Memory Profiling for UWP applications?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, memory-leaks, unmanaged-memory

I have been on the search to find a tool or a technique or anything that could help me find which
objects from my UWP application is allocating on unmanaged heap memory.

I tried looking at **WPR/WPA** combination for tracing object. But, did not find anything useful there.
(If you have any good links for UWP/WPF apps with this combo, please share)

I installed **Ant Memory profiler**, but they do not seem to have any option for Windows Store apps anymore.

I checked **.NET memory profiler**, when I try to load "Windows Store App" .. .NET profiler keeps being stuck at "Trying to load .NET memory"... stays stuck.

I am looking for any way/technique/tool that could help me have an understanding of the unmanaged
memory leak issues.

The Application I am working on... it has .NET core components,  Native CPP component,  UWP components,
it's hard to trace where the memory leak issue is occurring without any broad strokes hint.

(PS: Currently, I am trying to check if I can do anything with WinDbg for analyzing heapdump of UWP app)

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When app is built in  Managed + Native mode..

From Diagnostic Tools and Performance Profiler.. it is possible to trace

Native memory using the Heap Profile feature.

[image]

[image]

But, caution, turning heap profiling on turns the application super slow... so, the duration of test should be limited as later when analyzing the recorded profile.. it will
take further time.